# How to create an image with text scroll with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

For my website I need an image with text scroll. An example can be found here: https://nyetimber.com, at the 'Our wines' section.

How do I build something like this?

Side question: how do I find out how the wine company did this on their website? Is there an easy way to do so with element inspector, perhaps?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is not a 'help me code site'. You need to produce your attempt to the problem so far. Kindly go through this post for more info - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you are asking about parallax scrolling effect. It can be applied for both images and text. There's no direct answer for your question, because you didn't upload any code sheet, but you can read more about this effect here:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp
2. https://medium.com/@dailyfire/pure-css-parallax-simple-tricks-da102d0ffdb9
3. https://alligator.io/css/pure-css-parallax/

Answer for you second question is that you can use your browser inspect (developer tool) and see the plugins/code that has been used.